# 1und1 https with .htaccess and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, https

Hello my hosting provider is 1and1. And I have a problem. I have this `.htaccess` - but now I need to switch to `https`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On
# Installation directory
RewriteBase /
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://drinky.me/index.php?path=$1 [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Now I have to incorporate this code. Who can help?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect All Web Traffic
If you have existing code in your `.htaccess`, add the following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I have add it and the the page will be broken -> https://drinky.me/

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On
# Installation directory
RewriteBase /
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://drinky.me/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]